# Dax - how to subtract one pivoted matrix column from another (power bi)

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

With the columns of a denormalized source table pivoted to value rows in a matrix, what DAX would calculate the difference between matrix columns?

Selecting columns in Dax are one thing, but when columns are on rows, then how to select them?

There are many examples with date differences or adjacent rows, but those don't work here.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your filter context with `CALCULATE` similar to this:

```
Difference1 =
CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[value1]), Table1[class] = "C") - 
CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[value1]), Table1[class] = "A")
```

Comment: Doesn't that create a separate column for each value row?

Comment: Probably. I was answering how to calculate the `C-A` column, not how to format your matrix.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm looking for a way to calculate C-A for the entire matrix column though.